# replace item names with new group name and sum the values of the group

Tags: sql

I have the following from another query

```
name | count
a    | 1000
b    | 100
c    | 100
d    | 100
x    | 100
y    | 100
z    | 100
```

I need to create the final results where `"a"` is left unchanged; names matching `'b', 'c', 'd'` are grouped as `"group_B"` with its new value as the sum of the three rows; all other names are grouped as `"others"` with its new value as the sum of all other names. Thank you!

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend changing the first query to append another column. If your original query is something like this:

```
SELECT things
FROM table
```

Change it to this:

```
SELECT 
things,
CASE 
    WHEN name='a' THEN NULL
    WHEN name IN ('b','c','d') THEN 'group_B'
    ELSE 'others'
END AS grouping
```

It should then be pretty easy to group your results how you like.

Comment: That worked! Although I did change it to WHEN name='a' THEN 'a' in the first query so that group on 'grouping' works. Thank you!